# Is there a better way to assign many members in a class which are inherited from the same class?

Tags: c++

I have codes as follows:

```
class CRedisGroupChecker :public CRedisClientBase
{
    SINGLETON(CRedisGroupChecker)
public:
    ~CRedisGroupChecker();
private:
    template<typename MessageType>
    bool loadConfig(MessageType message) {
        if (!connectAndSelect(DB_NO_ZONE_INFO_CONFIG)) {
            return false;
        }
        auto type_name = message->GetTypeName();
        auto reply_future = m_oClient.get(type_name);
        m_oClient.commit();

        auto reply = reply_future.get();
        if (reply.is_string()) {
            return utils::messageFromJsonString(message, reply.as_string());
        }

        return false;
    }
   template<typename...MessageType>
   bool doLoad(MessageType&... args) {
      bool dummy[sizeof...(MessageType)] = { loadConfig(&args)... };
      for (auto iter = std::begin(dummy); iter != std::end(dummy); ++iter) {
          if (!(*iter)) {
              return false;
          }
     }
       return true;
   }
public:
    bool load() {
        return doLoad(level_zh, level_map_config, level_session_end_reward_config, level_score_star_config
            , level_daily_reward_config, rank_reward_config, level_upgrade_config, level_winstreak_config);
    }
public:
    pb::paiwei::Level_ZH                    level_zh;
    pb::paiwei::LevelMapConfig              level_map_config;
    pb::paiwei::LevelSessionEndRewardConfig level_session_end_reward_config;
    pb::paiwei::LevelScoreStarConfig        level_score_star_config;
    pb::paiwei::LevelDailyRewardConfig      level_daily_reward_config;
    pb::paiwei::RankRewardConfig            rank_reward_config;
    pb::paiwei::LevelUpgradeConfig          level_upgrade_config;
    pb::paiwei::LevelWinstreakConfig        level_winstreak_config;
};
```

The code above is to assign many members which are inherited from class Message in a class, I used the variable parameter function for passing the parameters. In the function doLoad,I used an initializer to expands "args...". "loadConfig(&arg)" is its pattern. I wanna know if there is another better way to achieve the goal which the "load" function do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C++17, you might use [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) instead of the (`dummy`) array trick

```
template<typename...MessageType>
bool doLoad(MessageType&... args) { return (loadConfig(&args) && ...); }
```

Another possible change is to use `std::tuple` for all members, and then use `std::apply` (we can get rid of `doLoad` which is an one liner):

```
bool load() {
    return std::apply([](auto&... args){ return (loadConfig(&args) && ...); }, configs);
}
public:
    std::tuple<
        pb::paiwei::Level_ZH,
        pb::paiwei::LevelMapConfig,
        pb::paiwei::LevelSessionEndRewardConfig,
        pb::paiwei::LevelScoreStarConfig,
        pb::paiwei::LevelDailyRewardConfig,
        pb::paiwei::RankRewardConfig,
        pb::paiwei::LevelUpgradeConfig,
        pb::paiwei::LevelWinstreakConfig> configs;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I wanna know more about the statement near loadConfig. what's the difference between using parenthesis and not using parenthesis? when I do not use parenthesis, like this:{return loadConfig(&args) && ...;}, a compile error occurred.May you illustrate it or give me some references I can learn?

Comment: C++17 adds [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and requires parents.